# Form submit with enter key acts wrong

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, sammy.js

I am using laravel and sammy.js for my application. My login form looks like this:

```
<form action="#/login" method="post">
<!-- inputs -->
</form>
```

Now, sammy.js catches it like this:

```
this.post('#/login',function(){
         //handle, send to laravel for login
        });
```

My problem is that if I press the enter key, apparently instead of submitting the form, which would result in `this.post('#/login')` event to be catched and the function to be executed, an HTTP request is already made, and the laravel route is requested. As the route does not exist, a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is thown.

Now, the question is: why does this happen? While pressing the "submit" button makes the login, hitting the enter key results in the error above.

I would like an actual solution to the problem, as well as an explanation of it, not patches like `e.preventDefault()` on keypress or `return false` in js.

Note: sammy is initialized correctly, the form is in the container on which sammy works and submitting using the enter key used to work in a previous version of the site. A lot has changed by now, so reverting is not a good option, so I would like an actual suggestion on how to solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: I have just tried it in firefox and it's even more weird as hitting enter goes to `myserver/# instead` of `myserver/#/login` as chrome does. 
Clicking the submit button works, login is made, and the correct url is displayed.

The reason I say it is even more weird is because my sammy init is on `myserver/#`, so it might reach that far, but not further

Answer (score 1):

citing section `4.10.22.2 Implicit submission` in the Html5 specification:

> User agents may establish a button in each form as being the form's
>   default button. This should be the first submit button in tree order
>   whose form owner is that form element, but user agents may pick
>   another button if another would be more appropriate for the platform.
>   If the platform supports letting the user submit a form implicitly
>   (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text
>   field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so must
>   cause the form's default button's activation behavior, if any, to be
>   run.

In a nutshell, hitting the Enter key will always submit the form (issue an Http request) regardless of SammyJs. Note that the enter key will submit the form even if there's not Submit button!

Are you returning false from the #/login Sammy route?

Comment: No, I am not returning false. Thing is, the only button contained inside the form is the one I am referring to- and it works. So does the submit button do something else than actually submit the form- and issue an HTTP request?
If you think it is needed, I can provide more code  :) 
Thanks